# A difficulty solving a limit

Tags: calculus, limits

Could anyone help me with this limit?

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} (\log_2^2 x - \sqrt{x})$$

All my usual method fail with this one, Wolfram Alpha looks at me funny, and I know the answers is $\ - \infty$, but have not idea whatsoever as to how to come to this conclusion.

Comment: $\sqrt x = log_2 2^\sqrt x$...

Comment: By $\log_2^2 x$, do you mean $\log_2\log_2 x$?  Or maybe $(\log_2 x)^2\ {}$?  Or something else?

Comment: The last one :) Meaning $\ (log_{2}x)^{2} $

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:
$$
\log_2^2 x -\sqrt{x}=\sqrt{x}\left(\frac{\log_2^2 x}{\sqrt{x}}-1\right)
$$

Comment: THANK YOU! My stupidity knows no limit apparently, because such an obvious solution eluded me :) I Appreciate your help immensely :)

Answer (score 0):

How about a substitution: sub your logx=t and express in terms of t. It will become evident